# Select the Max Date < Specified Date

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table, PartDescriptions:

```
ID|PartNumber|PartPrice|DateEffective
1 | AA001    |$0.10    |1/1/2016
2 | AA002    |$0.20    |1/1/2016
3 | AA003    |$0.30    |1/1/2016
4 | AA001    |$0.15    |10/20/2016
```

I have a form with an order date field.  I want a query that's going to select the max DateEffective that's less than the order date field on my form.  That is, if my order date is 10/22/2016, for part AA001, I want it to select the price of $0.15 (the one effective on 10/20/2016), and all other part prices effective 1/1/2016, but if my order date is 10/19/2016, I want it to select the price of $0.10 for AA001.

This is all to avoid having to write the prices to a table, but instead only call on them when I need to run a report for specific orders at any time.

Comment: `This is all to avoid having to write the prices to a table`. Why? It's common practices to stores actual prices in order lines, invoice lines et cetera. Reason being that in time prices change and data retrieval based on historical data can be a pain in the *ss. Not mentioning possible performance issues. Having said that, what have you tried so far yourself (you should not expect us to create your queries for you)?

Answer (score 0):

I have not had a chance to test it so it may need tweaking to work but basically:

```
SELECT PartPrice FROM PartDescriptions WHERE PartNumber='AA001' AND DateEffective IN
(SELECT Max(DateEffective) FROM PartDescriptions WHERE PartNumber='AA001' and DateEffective<=#10/22/2016#)
```